# Flutter Design Creatation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-design

I am new to flutter i want to create a design like SPEED HUMPS in flutter. but i don't know how to create it please help me.

I tried design. but i just made half round else the side lines are pending. so i need to make full design please help me below is my half round code.

---

### design it like ********Half Round******** or **********/----------_**********__

Comment: can you include your current code-snippet and image that are you trying to get

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.